# Number of hats across all my accounts

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2016

How can I find out the total number of hats I have across all of my accounts?

I'm not looking for the number of Unique Hats - that is easy to find.

Comment: If you've earned the same hat on 2 sites are you counting that as 2 or 1?

Comment: @RobertLongson 2. Otherwise I know how to find the answer :)

Comment: As far as I can tell, you'll have to count them manually when setting your Winterbash hat. The network-wide leaderboard only identifies the site where you have the most hats on, not the total hat count (including duplicates).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just go to your profile, the click on "Account", then click the blue hat with the number on it.

[image]

Then select any hat that you have earned then it will tell you what it is, how you got it unless it's a secret hat, and on which site(s) you got it from. You have as of this answer, 17 unique hats and 84 total hats earned. Of course, there is good old fashioned counting.

Comment: Thanks for doing the adding up for me! I was wondering if there is an easier way :)

Answer (score 5):

The Easiest Way

http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/

Then go to leader boards,

http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/leaderboard

Then Whole SE network

http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network

Then its the 1st one, then hover over your name. Apparently I have 23 hats. Thanks @balpha!

[image: hats]

If it's complete total, do some counting, and count the total amount of notifications on your snowflake.

[image: count gosh darn it]

Or you could do some more math and count how many times you earned a hat then add all of them.

Find out on your profile.

[image: simple as crap]

Then see that for all of them, then add all of them.

EX: bleh has

```
 4 I am your father's
 6 Just here for the hat's
 2 925's
+_______
=12 total hats
```

Comment: Those mechanisms count unique hats.

Comment: That gives unique hats, not total hats.

Comment: Added in. You didn't specify at 1st T_T

Comment: You have a lot more hats than just 12. You have like 12 total secret hats and you only included 3 of 9 of your unique hats!

Comment: I do. Who said bleh was the same as bleh? ;)

Comment: The 4 "I Am Your Father" hats in the screenshot?

Comment: That one is me. Bleh is another bleh. ;)

Comment: On mouse-based devices you can hover the cursor over the hat count in the leaderboard (the "9" in your screenshot). The tooltip will give you the answer.